# A button with changable label

Tags: dm-script

all

I'd like to create a button, whose function is to enable and disable other widgets. At first, the label of this button is Enable. When I click the Enable button, the label of this button will change to Disable. Is that possible?

Regards

Chen ZX

Comment: Previously there is another question in this post. I'd like to know how to use different action function for Enable and Disable buttons. That makes someone thought the question is not focused. @BmyGuest

Comment: The function of the button will always be the single called method you specify. It is up to you to use that method to split into different actions f.e. by checking the current label like I did in the example with the if/else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is certainly possible. You change the label of a push-button using the `DLGTitle()` command.

Here is an example:

```c
class CButtonDemo : UIFrame
{
    void OnButtonPressed(object self)
    {
            TagGroup buttonTG = self.LookupElement("ToggleButton")
            string oldLabel = buttonTG.DLGGetTitle()
            if ("Disabled" == oldLabel )
                buttonTG.DLGTitle("Enabled")
            else
                buttonTG.DLGTitle("Disabled")
    }
    
    object Launch(object self)
    {
        TagGroup dlg,dlgItems
        dlg = DLGCreateDialog("Test",dlgItems)      
        
        TagGroup label = DLGCreateLabel("This button toggles its label:")
        TagGroup button = DLGCreatePushButton("Disabled","OnButtonPressed").DLGIdentifier("ToggleButton")
        dlg.DLGAddElement(DLGGroupItems(label,button).DLGTableLayout(2,1,0))
        
        self.Init(dlg).Display("Test button")
        
    }
}

Alloc(CButtonDemo).Launch()
```